# styling rails links and adding icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

I would like to add icon instead of the text "delate" for the link to delete the object.
How should I do it? I am using font awesome, so code for icon looks like that:

```
<i class="fa-trash-o"></i>
```

here is the link from rails:

```
 <%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/trey/1739889

Answer (score 1):

Check out the examples section: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to  p, method: :delete do %>
  <i class="fa-trash-o"></i> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the class to the link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", p, method: :delete, class: "fa-trash-o" %>
```